# How can I only accept integer input without try catch in Java

Tags: java

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of bars(min 1 / max 6): ");
int barNumbers = keyboard.nextInt();
while (barNumbers <= 0 || barNumbers >= 7) {
  System.out.println("Enter number of bars(min 1 / max 6): ");
  barNumbers = keyboard.nextInt();
}
int barHeights[] = new int[barNumbers];
int countForBars = 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= barNumbers - 1; i++) {
  System.out.println(
      "Enter height of bar " + countForBars + " of " + barNumbers + "(min 1 / max 7): ");
  barHeights[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
  while (barHeights[i] <= 0 || barHeights[i] >= 8) {
    System.out.println(
        "Enter height of bar " + countForBars + " of " + barNumbers + "(min 1 / max 7): ");
    barHeights[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
  }
  countForBars += 1;
}
```

Hi guys, I need some  help which can be very easy for you because I'm a beginner of Java.
Anyway, I'm now trying to control a robot arm to convey stuff through Java.
The problem is that as you see there, I set some conditions to only get integer numbers between 1-6. So rest of inputs must be restricted especially string. So how can I restrict string input instead of using try catch stuff? If there is any helpful solution, I would appreciate of it. Cheers! And sorry for the code indication. I don't know how to make it like a code :(

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: @Allen for starters, look at the preview, and make sure it doesn't say "`enter code here`" on every line.

Comment: Java is exception-based. We use exceptions for everything. What is the reason to avoid it??

Comment: Why are a lot of people afraid of exceptions? :/

Comment: Exceptions can incur a lot of overhead, e.g. to build the stack trace. If you can avoid that cheaply, why not. You can avoid it by using `keyboard.hasNextLine()` and `keyboard.nextLine()`, and checking that the resulting string is exactly 1 character long and `str.charAt(0) >= '1' && str.charAt(0) <= '6'`.

Comment: Effective Java Item 39: Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try the following code:

```
 public static boolean isInteger(String str) { //pass your "keyboard" string here.
 if (str == null) { // if there is nothing entered in the String
    return false;
 }
 int length = str.length();
 if (length == 0) {
    return false;
 }
 int i = 0;
 if (str.charAt(0) == '-') {
    if (length == 1) {
        return false;
    }

 }
for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c < '0' || c > '6') {
        return false;
     }
   }
return true;
}
```

Comment: @Allen- Did you find this useful?